# Parse UML class diagram with PlantUML Java API

Tags: java, plantuml

I want to parse an existing PlantUML class diagram in order to implement my own DDL code generator.
As a first step I'm trying to parse a *.puml file containing the class diagram from Java, by using the [plantuml-mit](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.plantuml/plantuml-mit/1.2023.9) library. The idea is, to be able to iterate over all the classes in the diagram.

How can I access the diagram elements from code? So far I've discovered this two classes, which both expect a UmlDatasource inctance in the constructor, but I'm unsure how to create these instances.

```
net.sourceforge.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagram
net.sourceforge.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramFactory
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use PlantUML's API? Someone did it with partial PEG.js grammar at https://github.com/bafolts/plantuml-code-generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer meanwhile, by reverse engineering the API's Java code.

```
String source = "@startuml\n" +
            PUT YOUR CLASS DIAGRAM HERE
            "@enduml";

SourceStringReader r = new SourceStringReader(source);
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("testGroovy2.png");
ClassDiagram cd = (ClassDiagram) r.getBlocks().get(0).getDiagram();
Collection<Quark<Entity>> classes = 
cd.getEntityFactory().root().getChildren();
classes.stream().forEach(c-> System.out.println(c));
```